# Sorting NSMutableArray by string date value within a object

Tags: sorting, nsarray, date-sorting

There is a NSMutableArray *listOfOrders;

Which consists number of model objects.

every object has a key value "dateAdded" i want to sort listOfOrders by dateAdded in Ascending order.

for e.g
// values in dictOrder will different 
    NSDictionary *dictOrder = @{@"idValue": @"12345", @"OName" : @"Abc", @"dateAdded" : @"2012-05-18 12:03:00.0" };

```
NSMutableArray *listOfOrders;
MyClass *class1 = [[MyClass alloc] initWithDict:dictOrder];
[listOfOrders addObject:class1];
[listOfOrders addObject:class2];
[listOfOrders addObject:class3];
[listOfOrders addObject:class4];
```

i want to sort the class object by dateAdded value.
pls note : dateAdded value will be in string format.

Comment: I have tried this.
but it didnt work
[listOfOrders sortUsingComparator:^(MyClass* dict1,MyClass* dict2) {

  NSString *dateString1 = [dict1 objectForKey:@"dateAdded"];
  NSString *dateString2 = [dict2 objectForKey:@"dateAdded"];
  NSDate *dateAdded1 = [self  dateFromDateString:dateString1];
  NSDate *dateAdded2 = [self  dateFromDateString:dateString2];
      return [dateAdded1 compare:dateAdded2];
}];

Comment: Yes i have logged both the values.
But it prints in the same order.

Also tried this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195774/sorting-array-based-on-date-and-time-with-two-dictionary-keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found any solution which sort the Objects within Array orderby value in Object's Dictionary.
So i have created dateAdded of NSString type in MYClass.
also assign the same date valye to dateAdded which is in dictOrder.

now it is sorting myclass objects by using sortUsingComparator method.